# How to use String format similar to NSString in Flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, nsstring, string-formatting

How can I use a string format like this with Flutter?

```
    static let sampleText  = “Stack Overflow is a user-oriented question and answer site about computer programming. Located within the Stack Exchange sites, Stack Overflow was founded in 2008 by %@ and %@”

    NSString(format: sampleText, Jeff Atwood, Joel Spolsky)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar in Dart we have String interpolation:

```
String name = 'John Doe';
int age = 30;

String interpolated = 'My name is $name and I\'m $age years old.';
```

More examples: [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-using-interpolation-to-compose-strings-and-values)